# Multiple pattern recognition in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with the following format :

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
```

and I'm interested in `COL2` (string) and `COL4` (number) . 
I need to verify, simultaneously that `COL2="PATTERN"` and that the `COL4` without decimals = 32 (for example) .

I know how to do the `COL2` pattern recognition doing something like:

```
awk -F"\t" '$2="PATTERN" {print }' file
```

but I've failed to impose the second condition or to combine both.

Any help to solve this problem will be welcomed .

Thanks

Comment: Here's a good awk primer I read a few days ago: http://ferd.ca/awk-in-20-minutes.html

Comment: Do not read/use that article, that author has no idea about awk and so makes multiple statements that are just plain wrong (e.g. `variables are all global` - no, they aren't, local variables are declared in function arg lists after the real args). He is clearly a beginner and that is probably just his own cheat-sheet where he's trying to make notes for himself by guessing how things work from his own observations rather than reading the documentation and is getting it wrong. To learn awk, get the book Effective Awk Programming by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
awk '$2 == "pattern" && int($4) == 32 {print $4}' file
```

I did a test here and it works:

```
echo "foo1 foo2 foo3 123.43" | awk '$2 == "foo2" && int($4) == 123 {print $4}'
output: 123.43
```

Comment: Well, that was simpler than i thought .
What could be done if i wanted to do it selecting the subtring before the dot . eg using cut ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The second condition is `^[0-9]$`. Chain the regexp using the `&&`.